# Include entity and count data from different table in asp.net entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables:

**Talbe 1 -  Items**

```
id |  item  | categoryId
________________________
1  |  item1 |      1 
2  |  item2 |      2
3  |  item3 |      2
```

**Table 2 - Categories**

```
categoryid |  categoryName
___________________________
1          |  iphones 
2          |  ipads 
3          |  ipods
```

Talbe 1 is dynamic, i.e. users add items, and I have View and want to display a table that shows Category and Number of Items in category.
I am using entity.

My models

**Item**

```
public int id { get; set }
public string item { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

**Category**

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string categoryName { get; set; }
public virtual Icollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

So I a confused how to count data in Items and attach to categories.
Thanks.

Comment: not clear your question , what do you need ? `Cascade DropDownList`

Comment: I want to pass a list of categories to my view, and next to each category I want to display how many items in category, just like  categoryName | items_in_category....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Count` method on your Items property when querying categories.

Create a view model for your view.

```
public class CategoryVm
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public int ItemCount {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action method, you can use LINQ to query the Category table and project the result to a collection of `CategoryVm`

```
public ActionResult Categories()
{
  var db = new YourDbContext();
  var categoryVmList = db.Categories.Select(x=> new CategoryVm { 
                                                    Id=x.Id, 
                                                    Name=x.Name,
                                                    ItemCount = x.Items.Count() }
                                           ).ToList();
  return View(categoryVmList);
}
```

Now in your view (`Categories.cshtml`) which is strongly typed to a list of `CategoryVm`, you can iterate through the list and display  the property values as needed.

```
@model List<CategoryVm>
<h2>Categories</h2>
@foreach(var cat in Model)
{
  <div>
    <p>@cat.Name <span>@cat.ItemCount</span></p>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have an error "No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - CategoryVms"

Comment: CategoryVm is the view model we created for the view. There is no need to do any mapping for that. We are reading the entity object values and assigning to this view model objects. Which line are you getting this error ? Are you using this class anywhere else ?

Comment: I don't use CategoryVm anywhere else, now I am getting error "The entity or complex type 'Model.CategoryVm' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: @IgorLevashov how did your precious error go away all of a sudden ? If you had copied my code as it is, it will not throw an error. Can you double check ?